# Does the Wisdom modifier apply on a lizard-monk's armor class?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits, armor-class, lizardfolk

Lizardfolk is a PC race from the book **Volo's Guide to Monsters**.

The Players Handbook says (Monk):

> Beginning at 1st level, while you are wearing no armor and not wielding a shield, your AC equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier + your Wisdom modifier.

Volo's Guide to Monsters says (Lizardfolk):

> You have tough, scaly skin. When you aren't wearing armor, your AC is 13 + your Dexterity modifier.

Both explanations saying that **this** is now your AC. But if I think about the meaning of the Wisdom bonus (feeling/knowing how the enemy is moving) I think a lizard-monk's armor class should be: 13 + your Dexterity modifier + your Wisdom modifier.

So the question is the same as the title: Does the Wisdom modifier apply on a lizard-monk's armor class?

Comment: It seems to me you have answered your own question...

Comment: Maybe. But I'm not sure. It feels kind of overpowered.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The lizard-monk's armour class would be:

- 10 + Dexterity mod + Wisdom mod

**or**

- 13 + Dexterity mod,

**not**

- 13 + Dexterity mod + Wisdom mod.

Page 14 of the PHB says:

> Some spells and class features give you a different way to calculate your AC. If you have multiple features that give you different ways to calculate your AC, you choose which one to use.

Both the lizard's *natural armour* and the monk's *unarmored defense* are 2 separate ways of calculating your AC, therefore you choose which one to use, not combine them.

Comment: Thanks. That makes it very clear. Even if it is against my own logic I will do it like the PHB says.

Comment: @Fabic, the reason for this is 5e's general policy of bounded accuracy, which requires that most bonuses of these types to not stack.

Answer (score 11):

It does not apply. Every character has a number of different *ways* to calculate their total AC, and they pick **one** of those.

Everyone gets the base AC calculation:

> 10 + Dex modifier

Lizardfolk gives you another calculation (if you're not wearing armor), namely:

> 13 + Dex modifier

Monk also gives you another calculation (if you're not wearing armor), namely:

> 10 + Dex modifier + Wis modifier

But you still need to pick one calculation.

This is the same as when you are wearing armor. If you are not wearing armor, your AC calculation is:

> 10 + dex

If you are wearing Chainmail, your AC calculation is:

> 16

You cannot combine these two and say "Well, I'm wearing Chainmail, so I should be getting 16 + Dex modifier by combining the two calculations."

You always have to pick *one* of the various calculations given to you.

(More examples of things you can't combine include Barbarian Unarmored Defense, or Sorcerer's Draconic Resilience.)

Comment: To add: items which give you only a +X modifier to your AC, like a shield, or a ring of shielding, do add to your AC.