# How to calculate constitution based armor class for a Loxodon barbarian in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ability-scores, armor-class

Loxodons have natural armor that is calculated using "12+con_mod"

Barbarians have unarmored defence calculated using "10+dex_mod+con_mod"

One of my players wants to be a Loxodon barbarian and I'm not sure how to handle their unarmored AC. As a long time DM it seems obvious that you can't stack the same modifier twice. But my player brought up a good point that I can't explain away. The natural armor and the unarmored defence come from different sources, one from biology and the other from lifestyle and training. It seems to make sense that unarmored defence stacks on top of the natural armor.

Like so (12+con_mod)+dex_mod+con_mod

Are there any official rules that would deal with this problem, or should I just decide for my table?

Comment: At least related: "[Does natural armor stack with unarmored defense?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53498)" and "[Does the Wisdom modifier apply on a lizard-monk's armor class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105766)" and "[Tortle Monk's Natural Armor and Unarmored Defense](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107250)" and "[How does Dragon Hide interact with monk AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141562)"

Comment: Thanks for the links, this answered it for me